# how to share high score in my android game and find 10 best scores using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my problem is how to share highscore in facebook for my app. 
I have an android game written with eclipse and I can correctly connect through Facebook using facebook SDK and facebook LoginButton.

I need to have all of the game player's high scores and compare them and find the 10 best scores of all of the users. I searched a lot and I found that using graph API would help me to do that. I used this code which was in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/scores in eclipse where I wanted to share the scores:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("score", "the score I get from the game");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/scores",

    params, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }).executeAsync();
```

but as I go to graph API explorer, I am just able to get my own score:

```
/me/scores
```

but I need to have all of the user's scores and compare them with each other. any idea if you have to help me in this kind of sharing. and aware me if the graph API is not a good way for this case.
I have checked similar questions but I didn't find a clear way.

Comment: You can only read the scores for a player and their friends, using `/APP_ID/scores`. If you want the top ten scores for _all_ players, then you will have to store them on your end (so that will require a server-side component of some sorts.)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, about the code you said when I enter that this error apears: "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: APP_ID". how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you replace it with your _actual_ app id? (And did you use a user access token for the request?)

Comment: I replaced the app_id now, but again I can just see my own user which is connected trough facebook. I clicked **Get Token** and then _get access token_ > _extended permisions_ > _publish-actions_ .I am new with graph API; do you mind tell me what else more than these I should do. thanks alot

Comment: `"id": "69***************",
  "scores": {
    "data": [
      {
        "score": 18000,
        "user": {
          "name": "Ati Mokhtary",
          "id": "658***************"
        }
      }
    ]
  }`

Comment: Well do you have any scores publishes for friends that are also using the app already? (And you and the friends might need to provide `user_friends` permission as well.)